# how to send scheduled mails with Mail?

Tags: mail.app, email, applescript, script

I would love to send mails in my apple mail scheduled!
What is the most comfortable way to do that?

only method i found: http://homepage.mac.com/aamann/Mail_Scripts.html
*(but this is quite tricky + buggy)*

Comment: nd this https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/30354/mail-scheduler/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mail.app has no built-in function to send scheduled mails. You can use Automator to achieve the same result, though.

Open Automator and select "New iCal Alarm". Drag "New Mail Message" to the workflow. It will bring up a small composition window, just like in Mail.app.

Drag "Send Outgoing Messages" to the workflow. You can test it at this point to make sure that it's properly set up.

Save it. iCal should automatically open, and you can drag the event wherever/whenever you like. The message will be sent when the alarm is triggered.

Comment: Good answer. Make sure to run the created alarm once with some test recipient, because macOS will require confirmation for running an app (which this is) for the first time. Otherwise the email will not get sent.